# How to get the sonar administration permission,when I use http.client.fluent.Request

Tags: java, curl, sonarqube

1. Firstly I want to get "http://my_host:9000/api/ce/activity" when I login with the admin account on the UI, it works. 
   when I want to get data with http.client.fluent.Request in java, it returned 403 fobbiden.

here is code:

```
String context = Request.Get("http://my_host:9000/api/ce/activity")
            .connectTimeout(60000)
            .socketTimeout(60000)
            .execute().returnContent().asString();
```

Now the question is : how can I get the data throw this way ?And how to get the permission use java http request?

2. I have read the document, and do this

   ```
   curl  admin:admin my_host:9000/api/ce/activity
   ```

   but it returned

   ```
   curl: (3) Illegal port number
   ```

   admin:admin is the 
   username and password of administrator.
   Now the second question is: Am I must use curl in the java code to use the api ? If not , how can I make it work use "http.client.fluent.Request" instead ?

Any help would be appriciated ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for google
I found out the answer,sonar use the http basic Authorization to check the user.
When use java to attach the sonar api ,we should ".setHeader("Authorization","Basic YWRtaW4d6Y4Rt3W4=")","YWRtaW4d6Y4Rt3W4=" is the base64(username:pwd).
Then we can get the permission.